# need italic dollar sign

Tags: math-mode, italic

I want to have not only italic numbers but also italic dollar sign in Latex math mode.

I found that some people get this with the \pounds symbol, however I do not achieve to do it and anyways this seems to be an undesired effect:
[Special sign \pounds changed to dollar sign in alignment surrounding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159473/special-sign-pounds-changed-to-dollar-sign-in-alignment-surrounding)

So what is the proper way to get an italic dollar sign? If numbers can be italic, sure the dollar sign can be, right?

**Added a minimal working example:**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\verb+\$+ & \$ & as expected\\
\verb+\textit{\$}+ & \textit{\$} & as expected\\
\verb+$\$$+ & $\$$ & as expected\\
\verb+$\mathit\$$+ & $\mathit\$$ & not expected\\
\verb+$\mathit{\mathchar"0024}$+ & $\mathit{\mathchar"0024}$ & not expected\\
\verb+$\mathit{\mathdollar}$+ & $\mathit{\mathdollar}$ & not expected\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\textit{\$}` works.

Comment: What you can't straightforwardly get is a maths mode italic dollar symbol. But is that really a problem?

Comment: `${\emph \$}$` and ` $\emph \$$` both work.

Comment: @AFeldman Yes, but presumably because it switches to text so it is essentially `\textit{}` ?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, `$\emph \$$` and `\textit{\$}` achieve the same output, which is the text-mode italic dollar. However I use non-italic and italic dollar signs quite close to each other, and now they look quite different. To make it look nice I ended up using only text-mode dollar signs: instead of `\$` I now use `\text{\$}` and for italic dollar I use `\textit{\$}` in math mode.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you only use letters and numbers in `\mathit` (no Greek uppercase, in particular), just change `\mathdollar` to respect the math group, adding `"7000` to the math code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \mathchardef\mathdollar=\the\numexpr"7000+\the\mathdollar\relax
}\x
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{T1}{cmr}{m}{it}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\verb+\$+ & \$ & as expected\\
\verb+\textit{\$}+ & \textit{\$} & as expected\\
\verb+$\$$+ & $\$$ & as expected\\
\verb+$\mathit{\$}$+ & $\mathit\$$ & as expected\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This requires changing the font associated to `\mathit` into one that's T1 encoded.

A different strategy is to redefine `\mathdollar` to use `\text` for the `\mathit` case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\AtBeginDocument{\sbox0{$\mathit{\xdef\mathitgroup{\the\fam}}$}}
\mathchardef\latexmathdollar=\mathdollar
\protected\def\mathdollar{%
  \ifnum\mathgroup=\mathitgroup
    \text{\normalfont\itshape\textdollar}%
  \else
    \latexmathdollar
  \fi
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\verb+\$+ & \$ & as expected\\
\verb+\textit{\$}+ & \textit{\$} & as expected\\
\verb+$\$$+ & $\$$ & as expected\\
\verb+$\mathit{\$}$+ & $\mathit\$$ & as expected\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same for both codes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hm, we have to get a little sketchy when we want to have an italic dollar sign in math mode. My plan is to:

1. use `\mathrm` in mathmode (`$$` that is)
2. call `\textit` *inside* `\mathrm`
3. typle `\$` inside `\textit`

Let's see if this works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Here we have an equation: $x + \mathrm{\textit{\$}} = \pounds$.

\end{document}
```

[image]
Turns out it does! No fancy coding or setting new commands, but it is somewhat long to type each time, especially if you will use it a lot in your document. So here, I do it the smart way; I set a new command altogether:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\dollarit}{\mathrm{\textit{\$}}}

\begin{document}

Here we have an equation: $x + \dollarit = \pounds$.

\end{document}
```

Now typing your document will be *much* easier as instead of typing the horror that is `\mathrm{\textit{\$}}` every time, you just write `\dollarit` and you're set!

Just a quick note: you don't necessarily have to write `\dollarit`, you can specify *your own command* so it will fit you the best (just replace `\dollarit` in the first curly brackets after `newcommand` with anything you want).

I wish you a good day. Cheers.

EDIT: You can also just put `\textit{\$}` in math mode and it will work. However, because of some deficiencies that come with mixing raw text mode with math environment I chose to suggest you the longer, but safer way to achieve result - **when not using roman letters** always surround `\text` environment with `\mathrm`; it saves lives. Here is an example of a problem that arises in the [opposite case](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98008/is-mathrm-really-preferable-to-text).